# breakpoint ignored after moving files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

All was working fine, until I decided to move some of the files into a directory. What a mistake !!

Not that this concerns only my created files, nothing about setting and various json files of vscode which I didn't moved.

Before:

```
/app.ts (in project root)
/apps/directory/controller.ts
/afile.ts
```

After:

```
/app.ts (not moved)
/src/apps/directory/controller.ts
/src/afile.ts
```

When I set a breakpoint and launch the debuger after moving files, breakpoint becomes black with message "VS Code: “Breakpoint ignored becasue generated code not found (source map problem?)”

I updated path in my code, and projects works fine... which prove the JS files are properly generated.
I deleted all js and map files and recompiled them.

Nothing will help. It seems vscode tries to look on old location. isn't there something to reset to get it working normally ?

All "sourceMaps" settings are set to true in launch.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, renaming 'scr' to 'source' or any other name resolved the issue. I don't know why, will open an issue on ts github.